# Partial Fraction Decomposition with x and y in numerator and denominator

Tags: partial-fractions

I am trying to find the partial fraction decomposition of

$$\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}$$

I got it down to $x^2+y^2 = (A+B)x+(A-B)y$, but I cannot simplify it down anymore. Is this the wrong approach or am I not seeing something?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I cannot get the formatting to work.

Comment: Please identify the variable and the (constant) parameter. Use polynomial division with remainder to reduce the degree of the numerator first.

Comment: y is a fixed point, but they can both be any number.

Comment: So $x$ is the variable, and the pfd would look like $A(x)+\frac{B}{x-y}+\frac{C}{x+y}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, you need to divide the polynomials so that the degree of the top (with respect to $x$) is less than the degree of the bottom.  In this case, we have
$$
\frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 - y^2} = \frac{(x^2-y^2) + 2y^2}{x^2 - y^2} = 1+\frac{2y^2}{x^2 - y^2}
$$
Now, we set
$$
\frac{2y^2}{x^2 - y^2} = \frac{A}{x-y} + \frac{B}{x+y}
$$
To get
$$
2y^2 = (A+B)x + (A-B)y
$$
Which gives us the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
A+B = 0\\
Ay-By = 2y^2
\end{cases}
$$